# 'typeof this' in javascript function works oddly

Tags: javascript, function, call, typeof

like below code:

```
function test()  { 
            console.log( typeof this ) 
}
test.call(3)
```

the code output 'object' in console. but if I remove `typeof` it output [Number: 3]

so why `typeof this`  not output number???

Comment: It's not a duplicate answer of the stated one, we have a different behaviour here, due to the `.call()` invocation.

Comment: @chsdk I don't understand, this is *exactly* what's discussed in the duplicate: `function dis() { return this }; dis.call(5)`

Comment: @deceze Yes you are right, but it was a little unclear due to the misleading title of the question and the long clarification in the accepted answer.

Comment: To clarify the problem here, `typeof this` returns  `object` inside your function because you are invoking it with `test.call(3);` where [**.call()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) is converting `3` to `object` as stated in the docs: *if the method is a function in non-strict mode , null and undefined will be replaced with the global object and **primitive values will be converted to objects***.

Comment: @chsdk  thanks so much, I got my problem, mark you.